# How to reduce duplicated code in tests by extracting parts of it in a function or by using it.each in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I was asked to reduce duplication in my tests by using it.each or creating a function. I am not sure how to go about this. I have other functions in the test suite that are not expecting errors. I am assuming I can put the two duplicated assertions below in a helper function but if you have a better suggestion, let me know. Thank you.

```
expect(<jest.Mock>fetch).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(TypeError);
```

test file:

```
it('should throw if no args were passed', async () => {
            expect.assertions(3);
            return readPricing().catch((e: Error) => {
                expect(<jest.Mock>fetch).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
                expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(TypeError);
                expect(e.message).toBe(
                    `The 'products' information is required to successfully be able to execute this request.`
                );
            });
        });

        it('should throw if no product IDs were passed', () => {
            expect.assertions(3);
            const noIdData = {
                products: [{ salesPrice: '60.00' }, { salesPrice: '80.00' }],
            };
            // @ts-expect-error
            return readPricing(noIdData).catch((e: Error) => {
                expect(<jest.Mock>fetch).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
                expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(TypeError);
                expect(e.message).toBe(`The 'productId' is required to successfully be able to execute this request.`);
            });
        });

        it('should throw if an empty array of products was passed', () => {
            expect.assertions(3);
            const noIdData = { products: [] };
            return readPricing(noIdData).catch((e: Error) => {
                expect(<jest.Mock>fetch).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
                expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(TypeError);
                expect(e.message).toBe(
                    `The 'products' information is required to successfully be able to execute this request.`
                );
            });
        });
```

I tried using it.each but was unsuccessfully able to set it up and I am not sure it is possible with the given inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`it.each()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout) should do the trick, you can achieve something like:

```
describe("temp", () => {
  const productInfoMissingErr = `The 'products' information is required to successfully be able to execute this request.`;
  const productIdMissingErr = `The 'products' information is required to successfully be able to execute this request.`;
  const noIdData = {
    products: [{ salesPrice: "60.00" }, { salesPrice: "80.00" }],
  };

  it.each([
    ["no args were passed", undefined, productInfoMissingErr],
    ["no product IDs were passed", noIdData, productInfoMissingErr],
    [
      "an empty array of products was passed",
      { products: [] },
      productIdMissingErr,
    ],
  ])("should throw if %s", (caseTitle, input, errMsg) => {
    return readPricing().catch((e: Error) => {
      expect.assertions(3);
      expect(<jest.Mock>fetch).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(TypeError);
      expect(e.message).toBe(errMsg);
    });
  });
});
```

Which should render the same messages:

```
  temp
    ✓ should throw if no args were passed (1 ms)
    ✓ should throw if no product IDs were passed
    ✓ should throw if an empty array of products was passed (1 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.226 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```